# Is this representation of the Kronecker delta as a summation correct?

Tags: summation, periodic-functions, kronecker-delta

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) provides the following representation of the Kronecker delta:

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\delta_{jk} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi(j-k)n/N}
\end{equation}

At first glance, there doesn't seem to be any issue. When $j=k$, the summation goes to one, otherwise it's zero. Except, that is not exactly true. Consider what happens when $j = k + mN$, where $m$ is some non-zero integer: the "Kronecker delta" is equal to 1, yet $j \ne k$. Surely this representation cannot be correct?

Why is this an issue? Let us look at what happens to a $2\pi$-periodic function in $\theta$,  $y(\theta)$, that consists of the sum of $N$ shifted versions of the following function $x(\theta)$ (another $2\pi$-periodic function):

\begin{equation}
y(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^N x(\theta - 2\pi n/N)
\end{equation}

where each of the shifted functions have been shifted by equal amounts, such that $y(\theta)$ is in fact a $2\pi/N$-periodic function: we can show that $y(\theta + 2\pi/N) = y(\theta)$.

$x(\theta)$ is a periodic function, so we can express it as a Fourier series:

\begin{equation}
x(\theta) = \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} x_j \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}j\theta}
\end{equation}

Therefore, $y(\theta)$ can be expressed as

\begin{equation}
y(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} x_j \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}j(\theta - 2\pi n/N)}
\end{equation}

Then, by changing the order of summation, we get

\begin{equation}
y(\theta) = \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} x_j \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}j\theta} \sum_{n=1}^N  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} 2\pi j n/N}
= \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} x_j \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}j\theta} N \delta_{j0}
\end{equation}

But, by the property of the Kronecker delta, this implies that $y(\theta) = N x_0$ is a constant value. However, this cannot be, since we can always choose $x(\theta)$ to ensure $y(\theta)$ is non-constant. Therefore, something has gone wrong, which I assume is due to the fact that the above representation of the Kronecker delta is misleading. Am I missing something from the above discussion?

The above summation representation instead seems to represent a Kronecker comb (mentioned later in the same article). Is this true? If so, is the article calling the above representation the Kronecker delta inaccurate, or am I missing an unstated assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is to be understood as being on the discrete circle, that is for $j$ and $k$ in $\mathbb Z / N\mathbb Z$.
You can rewrite this on the discrete line:
$$ \sum_{p\in\mathbb Z}\delta_{j(k+pN)} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi(j-k)n/N}
$$
Technically, this is the discrete form of the Poisson summation formula.